# Alternatives to sliding window frames with RANGE on snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm migrate some BigQuery code to snowflake, and I'm having a little trouble to using Window function with range. This is because on Snowflake range sliding window frames is not supported.
I need to use "RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW" logic
any thoughts on how we can replicate this logic on snowflake?

```
WITH base AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 7 AS num
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS num
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS num
    UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS num
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS num
    UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS num
    UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS num
))
SELECT
num,
COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY num ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS row_count,
COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY num RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS range_count,
SUM(num) OVER (ORDER BY num ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS row_sum,
SUM(num) OVER (ORDER BY num RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS range_sum
FROM base
ORDER BY num
```

Expecting result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSRVL.png)

Comment: Hi Thiago - we’re aware of this limitation and planning to remove it in the future. I see that you got this example from https://sonra.io/2017/08/22/window-function-rows-and-range-on-redshift-and-bigquery/. Do you have a specific use case in mind, so we can find a case specific solution in the mean time?

Comment: (for the record: the limitation is that `OVER()` supports `ROWS BETWEEN`, but not `RANGE BETWEEN`)

Comment: Hi Felipe, thank you for your reply. I need to replicate this code below on snowflake:

`MIN(seq_inv)           OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_id             ORDER BY  UNIX_SECONDS(CAST(last_update_date AS TIMESTAMP)) RANGE BETWEEN 900 PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING) l15m_inv`

Comment: Get min of sequence value, based on the last 15 minutes from the last_update_date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the specific question from the comments: You can solve this with a sub-query.

For example, here I will find the MIN(previous value) for each row, looking back 365 days, and partitioning by customer:

```sql
with DATA as (
  select *
  from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.ORDERS
)

select O_CUSTKEY, O_ORDERDATE, O_TOTALPRICE
  , (
    select min(O_TOTALPRICE) 
    from DATA 
    where A.O_CUSTKEY=O_CUSTKEY
    and O_ORDERDATE between A.O_ORDERDATE-365 and A.O_ORDERDATE
  ) min_value
from DATA A
order by O_CUSTKEY, O_ORDERDATE
limit 10;
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this same approach be possible with more partitions? Like adding ORDER_STATUS and ORDER_PRIORITY

Comment: For sure - let's start a new question for us to explore further :)

Comment: Done! You'll find it here, Felipe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71662600/workaround-on-sliding-window-function-in-snowflake